# How to generate time based UUIDs?

Tags: java, uuid

I want to generate time-based universally unique identifier (UUID) in Java.

The method [`java.util.UUID.randomUUID()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID()) generates a [UUID Version 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_(random)) where 122 of the 128 bits are from a [cryptographically-strong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_cryptography#Cryptographically_strong_algorithms) random number generator.

How to generate a [Version 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_1_(date-time_and_MAC_address)) (time based) UUID ? Is there a separate library for that or is it some how provided in the Java 7 API and I am missing it.

Comment: No, the Java SDK does not include a different UUID class than `UUID`.

Comment: The UUID class however provides methods such as public long timestamp() to get the timestamp from the UUID if it is time based.. but theres no method to generate it

Comment: Check out JUG @ http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JugHome, it can do type 1.

Comment: JUG works pretty nice !

Comment: By the way, FYI, work is underway to [define new Versions 6, 7, and 8](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-peabody-dispatch-new-uuid-format-04.html#name-table-of-contents-2) of UUID.

Answer (score 16):

FasterXML Java Uuid Generator (JUG)

https://github.com/cowtowncoder/java-uuid-generator

```
UUID uuid = Generators.timeBasedGenerator().generate();
```

Comment: Will it produce same uuid's if called simultaneously, or produce unique uuid's?

Comment: It depends.  It *looks* like it will generate unique uuids if generation is done within one JVM.  However, if there are multiple JVMs on the same host generating time based UUIDs, I *think* you could get non-unique UUIDs.

Answer (score 16):

## Version 1 represents a point in space *and* time

[Version 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_1_(date-time_and_MAC_address)) UUIDs actually represent a point in space *and* in time.

The "space" part is the [MAC address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) taken from the networking port of the computer to uniquely identify where the id was generated (nearly unique, there have been some infamous screw-ups in assigning MAC addresses by the networking hardware manufacturers).

The "time" part is a 60-bit timestamp, being the number of 100-[nanosecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) intervals since [midnight 15 October 1582](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar#Adoption) [Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

## Java omits Version 1

As you have noticed, no implementation of Version 1 UUID is required by the Java specifications.

Presumably this is because of the security and privacy concerns from potentially divulging your MAC address and the moment of creation.

## 3rd party implementations

As seen on the other Answers, there are 3rd-party implementations of Version 1 UUIDs available.

Asking for library recommendations is off-topic here on Stack Overflow. So I asked on the sister site, *Software Recommendations Stack Exchange*, the question [*Library to generate Version 1 UUIDs to be called from Java*](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/75168/1255).

And here is a condensed list of the implementations mentioned in other Answers here and elsewhere that seem to still be actively supported.

- [*UUID Creator*](https://github.com/f4b6a3/uuid-creator#uuid-creator) providing Versions 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6.
- [*Java Uuid Generator (JUG)*](https://github.com/cowtowncoder/java-uuid-generator) originally by Tatu Saloranta.
- [`TimeUUID`](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/utils/TimeUUID.java) or [`UUIDGen`](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/utils/UUIDGen.java) class source code, part of the [*Apache Cassandra*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Cassandra) project. This source code is published under the Apache 2 license.

## UUID Version 6

FYI, work has been underway in recent years to define new versions of UUID. The most critically important is [Version 6](http://gh.peabody.io/uuidv6/), rearranging the date-time bits to make them friendlier to database indexing.

Comment: That is a very nice summary.

Comment: Cassandra's UUIDGen was refactored to [TimeUUID](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/utils/TimeUUID.java)

Answer (score 14):

```
String timeuuid = com.datastax.driver.core.utils.UUIDs.timeBased().toString();
```

have a look at
https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/utils/UUIDs.html

Comment: Is it a good solution for my case where I want to save hundreds of thousands record in Cassandra with unique IDs? For example it may happen that within a 1 second I have to generate 600 000 unique Ids...

Answer (score 10):

Be very careful using com.eaio.uuid.UUID, if you need to generate GUID by time other than current time, as this will always generate the same UUID for given time. So if your data has requirement to generate UUID, where records may have same time, this will generate same UUID.

We needed this to generate UUID for records, which are created ahead and also multiple records at same time, we tried to tweak it by trying to use UUIDGen.createTime(). We found that it has a side effect to mutate the time for records out of order.  If a subsequent request to create `UUID` has a time stamp older than previous request, you end up having a `UUID`, which is based on previous request's time stamp.

After all the analysis, we had to simply go back to create `UUID` at the time of creation, so that we don't have to pass it as an argument. Whichever solution we come up with to generate `UUID` at a later time, every one has a drawback.

Answer (score 9):

## *UUID Creator* library

Here is another way to generate time-based UUIDs using the open-source project [*UUID Creator*](https://github.com/f4b6a3/uuid-creator):

```java
UUID uuid = UuidCreator.getTimeBased();
```

## Version 6 *Time-Ordered* UUID

This library can also generate time-ordered UUIDs, aka UUID v6.

UUID v6, v7, & v8 are [proposed additions](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-peabody-dispatch-new-uuid-format-02#section-4.3) to [RFC 4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122). *The draft is being discussed in a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/uuid6/uuid6-ietf-draft)*.

See the articles [here](https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/12/19/store-uuid-optimized-way/) and [here](http://gh.peabody.io/uuidv6/) to understand the reason for new UUIDs.

An implementation of v6 can be found on that same [*UUID Creator*](https://github.com/f4b6a3/uuid-creator) library. See this exemple:

```java
UUID uuid = UuidCreator.getTimeOrdered();
```

---

**Disclaimer**: I'm the main contributor of `uuid-creator`.

Comment: This Version 6 proposal would be quite valuable for use in databases to enable better indexing. Thanks for making this known.

Comment: At a quick reading, this Version 6 appears to be compatible with [the reordering logic I implemented in my utility library](https://github.com/chrylis/time-based-uuid-reordering/blob/master/src/main/java/com/chrylis/lib/time_based_uuid_reordering/TimeBasedUuidReordering.java#L35-L45); can you confirm?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- yes, confirmed. It is the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

To test our application, we have to generate data which has time-based UUID, using com.eaio.uuid.UUID we generated old time stamp UUIDs and hence were able to control the timestamp as per our test cases. 
**Note**: - We cannot generate future timestamp UUID

We generated in below way -

```
import com.eaio.uuid.UUID;
import com.eaio.uuid.UUIDGen;

    long time = DateUtil.getEpochtimeFromDate("21-06-2018 12:30:31", "dd-M-yyy hh:hh:ss");
    UUID time_based_uuid = new UUID(UUIDGen.createTime(time), UUIDGen.getClockSeqAndNode());
```

Answer (score 1):

[Cassandra's implementation](https://gitbox.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cassandra.git;a=blob;f=src/java/org/apache/cassandra/utils/UUIDGen.java;hb=HEAD) or in [Github](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/utils/UUIDGen.java) of type 1 UUID: [usage](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.cassandra.utils.UUIDGen)
Do note that you do not compare these uuids like uuid1>uuid2 etc because of known [bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7025832)

Answer (score 1):

To generate time based UUIDs in maven project you have add the dependency of Generator that is generate time based UUIDs.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.uuid</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-uuid-generator</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

If you have a normal java project you have to import library of Generator
 [java-uuid-generator](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/com.fasterxml.uuid/java-uuid-generator/3.1.4/source-code).

Then generate the UUID:

```
UUID uuid= Generators.timeBasedGenerator().generate();
```

Now if you want to check the UUID time and date [check here](https://www.famkruithof.net/uuid/uuidgen).

Enter generated UUID and your current time zone.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't interested in integrating Yet Another Java Library™️, here's a bit of Java code to generate Version 1 UUIDs. Home brew, so YMMV.

Pre-conditions:

- clock sequence: [RFC 4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122#section-4.2) goes into a bit of details what it ideally should be, but then hand waves it with "it can be a pseudo random number", so that's what we use here.
- node id: the RFC wants this to be a MAC address - I leave getting a relevant MAC address as an exercise to the reader, and in this implementation we rely on more hand waving from the RFC and use a bunch of random bytes in the correct amount, instead.

```java
// fake clock_sequence and node_id
var rng = SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong();
short clock_sequence = (short) rng.nextInt(0x10000);
byte[] node = new byte[6];
rng.nextBytes(node);

Instant time = Instant.now(); // if you don't want "now", pick something else
var dur = Duration.between(ZonedDateTime.of(1582, 10, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        ZoneOffset.UTC), // RFC-specified epoch, no idea why
        time.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC));
var timestamp = dur.getSeconds() * 10000 + dur.getNano() / 100;
var time_low = timestamp & 0xFFFFFFFFL;
timestamp >>>= 32;
var time_mid = timestamp & 0xFFFFL;
timestamp >>>= 16;
var time_high_and_ver = timestamp & 0xFFF | (1 << 12); // add version 1
var msb = time_low << 32 | time_mid << 16 | time_high_and_ver;

ByteBuffer data = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);
data.putShort(clock_sequence & 0x3FFF | 0x8000); // add RFC variant
data.put(node);
data.flip();
var lsb = data.getLong();

// compose the UUID
return new java.util.UUID(msb, lsb);
```

The full implementation is also available, MIT licensed, for download at https://github.com/guss77/java-uuid