# Is there a way to generate timestamp based uuid?

Tags: java

Reading document, I saw there are four types of uuid. I am wondering how to generate type 1(timestamp based) and type2 (DCE security based) uuid. Any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244897/how-to-generate-time-based-uuids?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate time based UUIDs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244897/how-to-generate-time-based-uuids)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also implement your own if for whatever reason you don't want to use [JUG](http://mediashelf.github.io/uuid-datepath-idmapper/generate_uuids.html) (as suggested above).

For this check the class [UUID](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html). You need to use [System.nanoTime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()) and ensure successive calls return increasing values (so if you get two times the same time value, then return the greatest returned value so far plus 1).

The layout of the UUID type 1 can be found in: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt