# Generate best UUIDs for big data

Tags: java, hadoop, uuid, bigdata

I want to generate unique identifier for big-data and ended up in UUID.  I referred Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) for UUID and the article mentions that *hash collision could be a probability* and *"The identifier size and generation process need to be selected so as to make this sufficiently improbable in practice"*.

*"...these probabilities only hold when the UUIDs are generated using sufficient entropy. Otherwise, the probability of duplicates could be significantly higher,..."*.

*"...Where this is not feasible, RFC4122 recommends using a namespace variant, such as as Type 5 UUID, instead."*.

I am planning to generate UUID using Java and referred the API https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html

Going by the Wikipedia:

1. How can I set the identifier size and select the generation process
   as pointed out in Wikipedia?
2. What should i do to meet the "sufficient entropy" mentioned over there?

   Can someone simplify this and let know what exactly I should do to
   generate the best UUIDs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I set the identifier size and select the generation process as pointed out in Wikipedia?

What identifier size? The size of UUID is specified by a standard.

> What should i do to meet the "sufficient entropy" mentioned over there?

Nothing. Just use `java.util.UUID`. From [documentation of `randomUUID`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID--):

> The UUID is generated using a cryptographically strong pseudo random number generator.

If it's cryptographically strong then it's good enough for you :)

Hey, if you are in doubt, just generate a bazzilion of UUID and check whether any two of them are the same :)

> what exactly I should do to generate the best UUIDs?

Well, if you don't know, then use UUID version 1. But if you need unpredictable or randomized values, then use UUID version 4.

Also keep in mind that if you need to build a database index from *a lot* of UUID values, then it is better to have these values somewhat incremental for better insertion performance - UUID version 1 is better in this situation than version 4.

---

Edit: It looks like the java.util.UUID API doesn't provide an easy way to generate version 1 UUIDs.  Hopefully this will help:

[How to generate time based UUIDs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244897/how-to-generate-time-based-uuids)