# Time-based UUID has less chance of conflict than random generated?

Tags: java, uuid

Java UUID: time-based UUID has less chance of conflict than random generated?

Time-based: UUID generated at a timestamp will not conflict with any UUID generated before or after the timestamp.

But a random-generated UUID may conflict with an UUID generated sometime in the past or in the future.

Is this true?  If true, why time-based UUID generation is not provided by Java?

Comment: this thread goes deep into this topic and is less subjective https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244897/how-to-generate-time-based-uuids

Comment: "May conflict" Sure.  Except the probability is around that of being struck by lightning, like, twelve days in a row.

Comment: @LouisWasserman - It depends where you are standing :-)

Answer (score 3):

> Is this true?

It is true in theory.  In practice:

1. MAC addresses are not necessarily unique<sup>1</sup>.
2. Generating timestamps and the "uniquifying" clock sequence (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_1_(date-time_and_MAC_address))) is a hard problem ... unless UUID generation is implemented as machine-wide service.

Note that if timestamp + clock sequence are not generated correctly, the probability that the uniqueness is violated is likely to be higher that for type 4 UUIDs.  (And that is pretty small ... )

> If true, why time-based UUID generation is not provided by Java?

That is a question that can only be answered by the developers.

However, I think that the root problem is implementing the uniquifying clock sequence when you have multiple JVMs running on a machine.  (Or when there are non-Java applications generating type 1 UUIDs.)

See the comments on https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=5059271

---

Note that there are also potential security concerns with *revealing* MAC addresses via type 1 UUIDs, but that (IMO) is not a reason not to implement them ... for use-cases where MAC addresses don't need to be secret.

---

<sup>1 - Operating systems typically allow the default (manufacturer supplied) MAC address of a network interface to be overridden.  And when you consider virtual machines, software defined networking and so on, the MAC addresses may be chosen randomly.</sup>

Comment: Thanks. For a cluster of JVM machines, How about using machine number(1,2,...) instead of MAC address. So UUID: timestamp + machine_number + random_bytes using constructor(bytes, bytes)?

Comment: 1) I don't see the benefit.  You still have random bytes and risk of the same random bytes appearing.  (And the probability is larger because the random space is a lot smaller.) 2) This is NOT how type 1 / 2 UUIDs work.  I read your question as being about those schemes.  3) This is not a *universal* scheme if it only works in >your< cluster.

Comment: If you are going to seriously propose a "better" kind of UUID, it is going to take a lot deeper level of thought and analysis than can be conveyed in a 2 line comment.  And then you have to convince a lot of people that the benefits of implementing a new scheme outweigh the costs involved in getting there.

Comment: That's true. Proposing a new kind of UUID is not easy. Significant work is being done to propose UUIDv7, which is essentially a k-sorted identifier. A new draft is being discussed written these days. Any one can join de discussion in this GitHub repository:

https://github.com/uuid6/uuid6-ietf-draft

Comment: thanks. For random UUID, does the java Random.bytes() generate random bytes of similar quality?

Comment: 1) `UUID` does not use `Random`.  It uses `SecureRandom`.  2) The quality of `SecureRandom` depends on service provider, and the OS source of entropy.  3) The same random number provider / source will be used for type 1/2 or type 4 uuids. 4) You don't **need** to ask me these question.  Read the source code.